GUI with tree view support in Golang
Scaleable Objects Persistence(SOP) framework needs a data browser UI, and since it is written in Golang, I am looking around for a GUI framework cross platform where this utility can be written in.
It has to be cross platform and supports rich widgets like "tree view".
I tried GIO UI but I can't find sample implementations for tree view. I am looking around for other MIT (low risk) open source licensed framework.
